# How shall I proceed with a wrong question?

Tags: discussion, support

I accidentally worded the following question wrongly:
[Why are the granules of pancreatic alpha cells larger than those of beta cells?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/59228/why-are-the-granules-of-pancreatic-alpha-cells-larger-than-those-of-beta-cells)

What shall I do now? Should I ask a new question or edit the existing question?

Will the OP of the current answer appreciate it if I change the question at this stage when it renders his answer basically meaningless?

Since the current question is incorrect, I would prefer to edit it.

Edit : Answerer could have have asked me in comments to recheck my question, rather than explaining in full length I exchanged the size of two.
I also believe this would waste my reputation(that is already too low) on bounty , for such non needed answer.

Comment: *"Answerer could have have asked me in comments"*... Yes, I could have asked you in the comments, I could have ignored your question, I could have done several different things. But the responsibility to check your question before posting it and before setting a bounty to it is yours, not mine. I just deleted my answer, since it is useless now. And thanks for the *"non needed answer"*, this is a really nice way to acknowledge someone who spent time finding information for you (I'm being ironic here).

Comment: By the way, deleting or not deleting my answer won't make any difference to your bounty. Since you seem to be so worried about the bounty, this is a useful information for you: you lost it. In SE sites, once you set a bounty, you lost those points forever. You cannot claim it back, or give it to yourself (if you write your own answer). If no one answers that question, you simply loose the points (actually, you already lost them).

Comment: Am I such a bad person? It would be much better, to ask a new question than to offend a senior for such pitty reason. Sorry for inconvenience.. I am asking a new question. I really never meant to offend you..

Comment: I'm not offended. I simply didn't appreciate the way you handled it, but that's just me. You don't need to ask a new question: since you edited the existing one, just wait until someone answers it.

Comment: I like rep, because that helps me set bounties, otherwise some of my questions are never answered. I had to draw attention towards them. I dont forget my question and they keep wandering in my brain forever until answered. Who in the world otherwise need these reps for? I had also not wanted your rep not to go in vain, reps may help you as well, so I insisted you to give an answer without me changing the question. I liked Bryans idea, *On other hand, someone answering that question could have included an answer to the reverse question.*

Comment: So I just wanted you to answer reverse queston.  I had already posted a new question and reverted back original... You may undelete your last answer.

Comment: I had not wanted site to have wrong questions, so I tried to close it. I could not close my question since it had bounty.

Comment: I like curious badge because I could not earn it on physics site as well( too many downvoted questions I had back then). This made me jealous of the badge..

Comment: @AnubhavGoel Although no one told you specifically what to do, the answers you got here when you asked on Meta were unanimously not to edit the question (there are good reasons for this), yet this is what you did.

Comment: @BryanKrause Mr Gerado and I had a conversation in comments of his answer. There he had suggested me to edit question. I was too immoral to decide what to do.

Comment: Ah okay, I missed that discussion.

Comment: I **did not** suggest that you edit the question initially, which would obviously render my answer useless. I explicitly said that I would delete my answer (which I did) and that you should edit your question (to your original intention) after you complained that I didn't answer the question.

Comment: Anyway, this is a completely unnecessary confusion.

Comment: I would better suggest question is closed by moderaters, rather than having a discussion full of negativity. That trivial question aint worth all this hastred.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado You may undelete your answer please. It is perfect for that question.

Comment: Nevermind, forget about that and let's move on.

Comment: I had, up untill Bryan reminded. I have my 1st proff exams from this tuesday. Had no time. But, I am again getting too many questions reading text especially biochemistry, I dont know what to do. Teachers in college are too scary...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What should the question have been? Generally spoken, when the edit is small and renders existing answers not worthless, the question should be edited.

However, assuming the intended question is very different than the [existing original question](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/59228/9943) and since [the answer](https://biology.stackexchange.com/a/63944/9943) has received 4 upvotes and seems to be qualitatively sound, I would recommend asking a new question, perhaps linking the [existing original question](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/59228/9943).

However, it all depends on how different the intended question is from the [existing original question](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/59228/9943).

Comment: The issue is it was asked the wrong way; the beta cell granules are larger. The problem with editing it is that it will invalidate the current answer. Unfortunately the current answer doesn't answer the question if it were phrased correctly, it simply refutes the basic premise.

Comment: @BryanKrause - gotcha. Kind of an interesting problem. In that case I would simply leave the post as is, but let's see what others have to say.

Comment: I think the only thing that can be done is to create a new question. Perhaps the old one should even be deleted, it's kind of a boring question (since it's wrong, and sort of easily provably wrong), although there was a lot of effort put into the answer. On the other hand, someone answering that question could have included an answer to the reverse question.

Comment: Answerer could have have asked me in comments to recheck my question, rather than explaining in full length I exchanged the size of two.

Comment: I also believe it would become wastage of my own rep for such non needed answer.

Comment: @BryanKrause What will happen to my rep(will it come back) , if question is deleted? I would also not get curious badge if more of my questions are deleted.

Comment: @BryanKrause Yes,  question is boring, I made a face as well my teacher asked it. Although he never gave answer.